# php returning value from mysql 2 times

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am using the code below to return value from sql but the value is displayed 2 times.

```
$cc=mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pass);
mysqli_select_db($cc,$database);
$sql = "SELECT b_id FROM ``ub_per`` WHERE ``b_email`` = '$mail'";
$res = mysqli_query($cc,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
foreach($row as $value){
  echo($value);
}
```

Comment: Use single backticks ` for your table and column name.

Comment: Possibly the content of $mail is contained twice in the table? Use `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: have you took a look to your table to see if it must display only one value ?

Comment: show table structure in your question please

Comment: actually the field i am trying to return is set as unique. so there isno chance of 2 results. but still i can't understand why i am getting this problem

Comment: Have you tried checking your table if there are two same `emails`? Or try running the SQL query in the backend?

Comment: use `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is a little more complex than that. 
So the row `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);` will return an array, I think if you check there will be 2 items in it.
Looking like this

```
$row[0] = id;
$row['b_id'] = id;
```

now you do

```
foreach($row as $value){
  echo($value);
}
```

So will echo id out twice.
Use
`$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC);` 
To get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It is because query gives you 2 results(rows).
Try:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($row);
```

And you will see if there are more than 1 rows in results.

Comment: actually the field i am  trying to return is set as unique. so there isno chance of 2 results. but still i can't understand why i am getting this problem